# PyQT QAbstractProxyModel mapToSource

Tags: sqlite, pyqt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I've setup my QTableView as view, model for that view is QSqlQueryModel.

[image]

Excuse me for Serbian letters, you will understand what I am saying nevertheless.

```
self.model = QSqlQueryModel(self)
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("database.db")
db.open()

view = self.ui.myView
view.setVisible(True)
view.setSortingEnabled(True)
view.sortByColumn(2,Qt.AscendingOrder)
view.setModel(self.model)

view.clicked.connect(self.clickedSlot) #this function clickedSlot returns row and column numbers, which I use for extracting data from SQLite database.

def searchName(self): #this function searches the model for some name,lets say JOHN DOE`

    name = (str(self.ui.inputName.text()).upper())

    proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel()
    proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
    proksi.setDynamicSortFilter(True)

    proxy.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp(name, Qt.CaseInsensitive))
    proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(1)

    view = self.ui.myView
    view.setVisible(False)
    view.resizeColumnsToContents()
    view.setVisible(True)
    view.setSortingEnabled(True)
    #view.sortByColumn(2,Qt.AscendingOrder)
    view.setModel(proxy)
    view.clicked.connect(self.clickedSlot)
```

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi7qZ.jpg), after the searchName function. Again, excuse me for Serbian letters. Now the problem;

If I clicked on a row in first screenshot, I would get row number and column number printed in console, like 8,2. 
If I click on a row in SECOND screenshot (one with the proxy filter ON) I get row -1, column -1.

How would I implement QAbstractProxyModel and mapToSource method to get REAL row and column numbers?

:edit:

```
def clickedSlot(self,index):
 rownumber = index.row()
 colnumber = index.column()
 self.model.setQuery("select name from cases")
 tempname = self.model.data(self.model.index(rownumber, 1))
 print("row " +str(rownumber))
 print("column " +str(colnumber))
 print("name " +str(tempname))
```

output I get with this:

row 9
column 1
name JOHN DOE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Let me preface by reassuring you... The Serbian letters were no trouble at all :-)*

I would need to see your code for the SLOT `self.clickedSlot` to be sure, but my guess is that you are resolving the row column wrong at that point.

Assuming `self.ui.myView` is the [QTableView](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtableview.html) and you are using the [clicked()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) signal, what you should be receiving in your `clickedSlot` is the [QModelIndex](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmodelindex.html) for the proxy model. At that point you should be able to do the following:

```py
def clickedSlot(self, modelIndex):
    model = modelIndex.model()
    if hasattr(model, 'mapToSource'):
        # We are a proxy model
        modelIndex = model.mapToSource(modelIndex)
    print modelIndex.row(), modelIndex.column()
```

This is just one way to check for the proxy. Maybe you have a flag set and you already know its a proxy. But here I just check if the model reference on the index has a '[mapToSource](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#mapToSource)' method, and if so then we know its a proxy. So we just call the `mapToSource` with that ProxyIndex to get the real index.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, I have a feeling that with your help @jdi I could get this sorted. 

I added a method in the original post.

Comment: Yes exactly. In your example you are getting the row and col first. If you add the check I suggested first, and change the model index if its a proxy, the rest if your code can be the same.

Comment: That's it! Code you provided is the solution to my problem.

I sincerely thank you, as this completes my application.